# CSS - different size buttons alignment

Tags: css

I would like to fix this but I am not quite sure how to do so. The other buttons need to adjust so that the equal button doesn't make them look splited. 
Thanks in advance! 
[misaligned calculator buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEGWb.png)

My css:

```css
body{
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
}
form{
    width:280px;
    margin: auto;
    
}


button{
    height: 40px;
    width: 60px;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    background-color: #ddd;
    border: none;
    float:left;
    margin: 2.3px;
    
    
    
    
}
button:hover{
    background-color: #bbb;
}

button:active{
    background-color:#aaa;
}

input{
    height: 40px;
    width: 246px;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    background-color: beige;
    border: none;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>JavaScript Calculator!</title></head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="calccss.css"> 

    
<body>
    <div >
    <form name="calc">
    <input class="inputc" type="text" name="panel" value="0" readonly="readonly"/> 

    
    
    
    
    <span><button type="button" onclick="onMouseClick()" value="C" name="c">C</button></span><span><button type="button" onclick="onMouseClick()" value="/" name="div">/</button></span><span><button type="button" value="X" onclick="onMouseClick()" name="x">X</button></span><span><button type="button" onclick="onMouseClick()" value="-" name="minus">-</button></span>
    
    <span><button type="button" onclick="onMouseClick()" value="7" name="seven">7</button></span> <span><button type="button" onclick="onMouseClick()" value="8" name="eight">8</button></span><span><button type="button" value="9" onclick="onMouseClick()" name="nine">9</button></span><span><button type="button" onclick="onMouseClick()" value="+" name="plus">+</button></span>
    
     <span><button type="button" onclick="onMouseClick()" value="4" name="four">4</button></span> <span><button type="button" onclick="onMouseClick()" value="5" name="five">5</button></span><span><button type="button" onclick="onMouseClick()" value="6" name="six">6</button></span><span><button type="button" style="height:128px" onclick="onMouseClick()" value="=" name="equals">=</button></span>
    
    <span><button type="button" value="1" onclick="onMouseClick()" name="one">1</button></span> <span><button type="button" onclick="onMouseClick()" value="2" name="two">2</button></span><span><button type="button" onclick="onMouseClick()" value="3" name="three">3</button></span>
    
    <span><button style ="width:125px" type="button" onclick="onMouseClick()" value="0" name="zero">0</button></span> <span><button type="button" onclick="onMouseClick()" value="coma" name="coma">,</button></span>
    
    </form></div>
     
<script src="calcjs.js"></script>   
</body>



</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could float: right the equals button.

You will need to adjust the width of your form element to keep it aligned, and I would recommend sticking with full pixel amounts of margin, etc., as not all browsers treat partial pixels the same.

Also, you might change the CSS such that the spans are floated, or simply remove the spans altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated html

```
<span><button type="button" style="height:128px;float:right;" onclick="onMouseClick()" value="=" name="equals">=</button></span>
```

Here is the [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/tDxk6TuTCknUJMGwHdLc?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks! I added margin-right:23px; margin-top:3px; to align it a little bit better.